# How to apply function by groups in array in R?

Tags: arrays, r, function

I have a 3d array with latitude, longitude and datetime (Year_Month_Day_Hour). Which is the best way in R to apply a function over the array by groups (in this case by years or month or days)? The result should be an array with the mean values. The 3 dimension is than the year, month or day.

```
str(data)
 num [1:7, 1:7, 1:5] 977 994 1010 1020 1026 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "60" "57.5" "55" "52.5" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "-30" "-27.5" "-25" "-22.5" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "2014_10_01_00" "2014_10_01_06" "2014_10_01_12" "2014_10_01_18" ...
```

Example (truncated):

```
dput(data) structure(c(977.2, 994.4, 1009.8, 1020.1, 1026.4, 1029.4, 1029.2, 
978.7, 995.7, 1010.2, 1020.5, 1026.5, 1028.8, 1028.3, 982, 997.5, 
1011.3, 1021.2, 1026.1, 1027.4, 1027.1, 986.2, 999.9, 1013, 1021.7, 
1025.1, 1025.7, 1026, 990.6, 1002.7, 1014.5, 1021.3, 1023.9, 
1024.7, 1025.6, 995.1, 1005.7, 1015.2, 1019.9, 1022.6, 1024.5, 
1025.9, 999.1, 1008, 1015.1, 1018.6, 1021.8, 1024.5, 1026.6, 
982.1, 998.9, 1011.8, 1020.1, 1025.5, 1028.4, 1028.8, 981.9, 
999.3, 1012.7, 1021.2, 1026.4, 1028.8, 1029, 983.9, 1000.2, 1013.5, 
1022.1, 1027, 1028.9, 1028.9, 987.1, 1001.8, 1014.6, 1022.7, 
1027.3, 1028.6, 1028.2, 990.9, 1004.1, 1016.1, 1023.3, 1027.2, 
1027.9, 1027.4, 995.1, 1006.9, 1017.8, 1023.8, 1026.8, 1027, 
1026.9, 999.5, 1010.1, 1019.1, 1023.8, 1025.9, 1026.1, 1026.9, 
990.3, 1002.3, 1010.9, 1018.3, 1024, 1027.6, 1028.6, 990.6, 1004.1, 
1013.2, 1020.8, 1026.2, 1029.3, 1029.8, 992.1, 1005.5, 1015.2, 
1023, 1028, 1030.4, 1030.5, 994.5, 1007, 1017.2, 1024.7, 1029.4, 
1031, 1030.3, 997.4, 1008.8, 1019, 1025.7, 1030, 1031, 1029.8, 
1000.1, 1010.9, 1020.9, 1026.5, 1030, 1030.6, 1029.5, 1002.9, 
1013.3, 1022.6, 1027.2, 1029.7, 1029.7, 1029.2, 993.6, 997.5, 
1001.3, 1007.4, 1015.5, 1022.7, 1026.4, 996.1, 1001.1, 1005.8, 
1012.7, 1020.1, 1025.6, 1027.9, 998.4, 1004.5, 1010.4, 1017.6, 
1023.8, 1027.6, 1029.1, 1000.2, 1007.3, 1014.4, 1021.5, 1026.4, 
1029, 1029.7, 1002, 1010, 1017.8, 1024.3, 1028.4, 1029.9, 1029.6, 
1004.3, 1012.9, 1020.7, 1026.3, 1029.7, 1030.2, 1029.3, 1006.9, 
1016, 1023.2, 1027.7, 1030.3, 1029.7, 1028.6, 987.9, 989.6, 995.1, 
1002.9, 1010.8, 1018.9, 1025.1, 989.8, 990, 995.1, 1004.7, 1013.9, 
1021.8, 1026.8, 993.1, 992.6, 998.1, 1008.8, 1018, 1024.6, 1028.3, 
996.9, 997.3, 1003.9, 1014, 1021.9, 1026.8, 1029.1, 1000.3, 1003.1, 
1010.5, 1019, 1025.2, 1028.5, 1029.6, 1003.6, 1008.7, 1016.4, 
1023.1, 1027.8, 1029.8, 1029.9, 1007.3, 1013.7, 1020.8, 1026.3, 
1029.8, 1030.2, 1029.6), .Dim = c(7L, 7L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
c("60", "57.5", "55", "52.5", "50", "47.5", "45"), c("-30", 
"-27.5", "-25", "-22.5", "-20", "-17.5", "-15"), c("2014_10_01_00", 
"2014_10_01_06", "2014_10_01_12", "2014_10_01_18", "2014_10_02_00"
)))
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
group <- as.factor(as.Date(dimnames(data)[[3]],format="%Y_%m_%d"))

aperm(apply(data,c(1,2), by, group, mean),c(2,3,1))
```

Comment: There are many similar questions on SO. You have several choices: converting to datetime- object or using substr() to form a grouping vector.

Comment: I have NO IDEA why this is so heavily downvoted and marked as closed.  I had this exact issue, found Xeo's description of the issue clear and reproducible, and even found the solution provided by Xeo better than the two answers given.  Maybe the question was heavily edited after a sloppy initial posting?  In any case, it's quite useful now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the dimension as the second argument in the `apply` function. For example summing with "Date" as margin:

```
> apply(array, 3, sum)
# 2014_10_01_00 2014_10_01_06 2014_10_01_12 2014_10_01_18 2014_10_02_00 
#       49691.3       49782.3       49919.6       49851.4       49639.0
```

If your dimensions have names you can also use the name as character string as the second argument.

---

**EDIT**

OP wants the results to be grouped by date. This function can maybe give guidance to the desired result:

```
myapply <- function(array, d, fun){
  # function to apply "fun" to "array"
  # which is of class array with dimension
  # 3. array is grouped by d which is a number
  # between 1 and 4
  # 1: year
  # 2: month
  # 3: day
  # 4: hour
  d.name <- strsplit(dimnames(array)[[3]], "_")

  # make groups
  names  <- lapply(d.name, function(x, d) 
                     paste(x[1:d], collapse= "_"), d = d)
  groups <- unique(names)

  # get the indices for the groups
  indices <- lapply(groups, function(x, names) 
                      which(unlist(names) %in% x), names = names)

  # compute the function on the groups
  results <- lapply(indices, function(ind, arr, fun) 
                       fun(as.vector(arr[,,ind])), arr = array, fun = fun)

  names(results) <- unlist(groups)
  return(results)
}
```

Results:

```
# mean grouping by day
myapply(array, 3, mean)
# $`2014_10_01`
# [1] 1016.554
# 
# $`2014_10_02`
# [1] 1013.041


# mean, grouping by hour
myapply(array, 4, mean)
# $`2014_10_01_00`
# [1] 1014.108
# 
# $`2014_10_01_06`
# [1] 1015.965
# 
# $`2014_10_01_12`
# [1] 1018.767
# 
# $`2014_10_01_18`
# [1] 1017.376
# 
# $`2014_10_02_00`
# [1] 1013.041
```

Comment: But I need to apply a function to groups of the 3 dimension. For example, the mean by day. In this case there is only one month and year. The results would be another array with the mean values for each month or year or day.

Comment: do you mean something like: `apply(array, c(1,2), mean)`

Comment: Yes and no, the problem is that the result with MARGIN=c(1,2) is a matrix with the mean values of all dates. But, when mean by month, it would be an array with mean values of each month.

Comment: so what exactly are months in your data?

Comment: Year_Month_Day_Hour is the format. But it can be day or year....its the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend tidying up your data. Right now we can't really tell what it looks like.

For grouping, create columns for your dates. I'm not sure what date "`2014_10_01_00`" might be, but if 2014 is the year and the month is October, split these into two columns. I don't think storing longtitude and latitude as type character makes sense, perhaps numeric might be better.

Second, check out the `data.table` package. It makes manipulating data (esp large ones) a breeze.

To use a function over the data table by different groups, do

```
my_dt[ , lapply(.SD, my_func), by = c("year", "month")]
```

where `year` and `month` are column names in your data table.